# How to use SQL "LIKE" operator by using wildcard?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

I am currently having trouble finding all rows that contain the following data in a table "%2" or "%20".

For Example: `'Susan rides%2bike across town'`.

```
SELECT * FROM [my_table] WHERE [description] LIKE % %2 %
```

I know this example will not work, however is there a way to search for these values "%2" or "%20" using the SQL "LIKE" operator? As I am required to find and replace them with a white space.

Comment: Are you, perhaps, after `LIKE '%[%]2%'`?

Comment: Hi @Larnu, I will quickly create a test table and test this theory quickly. Will revert as soon as possible, thank you.

Comment: Another option is to use `ESCAPE`: `LIKE '%\%2%' ESCAPE '\'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for this.

```
SELECT * FROM [my_table] WHERE [description] LIKE '%[%]2%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE description LIKE '%\%2%' ESCAPE '\';
```

For the `LIKE` keyword you can specify the `ESCAPE` sequence afterwards. In this example the leading backwards slash escapes the `%` so it will be interpreted as literal value.

Read more about it in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

you can test it in this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6b0ab/3).

Answer (score 0):

[image]The solution for the above stated probelem is

```
select * from my_table where description like'%[%]2%'
```

Comment: Please don't add statements to the answer such as asking the OP to mark the answer as the solution; it is just noise. if the OP feels that the answer answered the question, they will mark it as such. There is, however, nothing wrong within reminding the OP in the comments should they reply with a "thanks this worked" with a comment like "You're welcome @{Display Name}. Please do mark the answer as the solution if it helped so that future readers know the answer was helpful." though also flag the "thanks" comment as conversational, and then a mod will clean both comments up.